# XML shape background color in not rendering

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-shape

I have defined a drawable XML file which contains two items. here is the code

First Here is MainActivity Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relLayout1">
        <include layout="@layout/layout_top_tabs"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@id/relLayout1"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <include layout="@layout/layout_center_viewpager"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_navigation"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In layout_bottom_navigation I have used BottomNavigationEX

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width ="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

  <com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavViewBar"
    android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_top"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu">

</com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx>

</RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

Then I have defined MenuItems like this in bottom_Navigation_menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_house"
    android:icon="@drawable/ring_cicle_home"
    android:title="">
</item>


<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ring_cicle_search"
    android:title="">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_circle"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_circle"
    android:title="">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_alert"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_alert"
    android:title="">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_android"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
    android:title="">
</item>
</menu>
```

Here is the ring_circle_search

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:innerRadius="25dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="5dp"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <solid android:color="@color/off_red" />

        <padding
            android:left="11dp"
            android:right="11dp"/>
    </shape>

</item>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="50dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

The preview is shown like this :

[image]

But the red background is not rendered in android devices. Rather it becomes primary color which is Blue.

Can anyone please specify what is the problem ?

Comment: Can share your `drawable/ic_search` and where you are using this drawble

Comment: Icons from android studio. I have just generated it. Noting more.

Comment: share you layout file where you are using this

Comment: Updated the question. Please review.

Comment: Did you try to set color using hex value (e.g. `<solid android:color="#F0F" />`)?

Comment: Yes No luck yet. Color always returns to it's default color which is blue.